# Rotoated image not rendering on canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas

The image included in the code doesn't render on the canvas. If I use any other landscape image, it works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = document.createElement("img");

image.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
}

image.src = "http://org.school66.group.us.west.2.s3.amazonaws.com/church.jpg"
// this image works perfectly fine 
// http://org.school66.group.us.west.2.s3.amazonaws.com/bookclub.jpg
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br>
<button id="clockwise">Rotate right</button>
<button id="counterclockwise">Rotate left</button>
```

Comment: Both provided images are working. https://jsfiddle.net/93p5akp2/ Where is your problem?

Comment: I am using chrome and it's not working there. I see it works in safari & ff. My primary browser is chrome... Thanks Felix

Comment: Do you have set `height` and `width` of the `canvas` element?

Comment: I get that from Image... 
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;

Comment: I tried it in chrome and the fiddle is working - don't know where your problem is.

Comment: the funny thing is same code works for all landscape images in all browser...but the potrait image doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: That's why I am struggling...I am using chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) and it constantly blanks out...

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};
img.src = "http://org.school66.group.us.west.2.s3.amazonaws.com/church.jpg";
```

Comment: I have tried that as well. It works in all browser except chrome. The canvas essentials blanks out...

Comment: then add a interval time like:
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};
setInterval(draw(), 100);

Comment: WHy would I need that? What you think might be happening? I am already drawing image onLoad...isn't drawImage synchronous?

Comment: I'm just redrawing on the previous drawing so when the IMG will finish loading it will be draw correctly​ and for a canvas it's not a problem to redraw on them it's just like painting